# Xcode 5 crashes on launch

Tags: xcode, macos, crash, xcode5, osx-mountain-lion

I had downloaded a copy of 4.6 to see if I can use some of the iOS5 SDK's (then forgot that those aren't included in that version (they were migrated from 4.3 when I was on Mountain Lion). Anyhow, now when I open Xcode 5 on Mavericks it crashes constantly when opening any project or starting a new one.

I tried unchecking version control (never been a problem before), I tried removing everything in the plug-in's folder.

Here's the crash log: http://pastebin.com/LQnUzKzt

In addition if you have any suggestions on installing iOS5 SDK and simulators for debugging some iOS 5 crashes [yes, I know it's like 1% of users:(] I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: It's crashing trying to read a string from its resources. I recommend you reinstall Xcode.

Comment: @user1118321 I've tried this... I'm so desperate, I'm reinstalling Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these simple steps -

1. Quit all open applications
2. Remove all .DS_Store old files using this code in your "Terminal" (located in /Applications/Utilities))

   `find / -name ".DS_Store"  -exec rm {} \;`
3. Set default view to "List View". So, head into Finder > View > Show View Options > Use as Defaults
4. Now, try to run your Xcode.